# Compare types to classes with type hinting

Tags: typescript

First of all, I can't do this and I don't know why

```
switch (typeof request) {
    case 'EnrollmentRequest':
```

`Type '"EnrollmentRequest"' is not comparable to type '"string" | "number" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"'.`

But what I would like to do is

```
switch (typeof request) {
    case type(EnrollmentRequest):
```

so that I can get type hinting from PhpStorm

Comment: What is the sentence with question mark?

Comment: @Misaz Sorry.  I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I don't exactly know what do you ask for? You have no sentence with question mark at end. Try to add to question sentence like **What is causing this error and how to prevent doing it?**

Comment: "First of all, I can't do this and I don't know why"

Comment: If I went to an electronics shop and said "My phone doesn't turn on."  Would they say, "Sorry, that sentence doesn't have a question mark at the end of it.  Are you telling me that you need me to dance a jig?"

Comment: I can't tell if you're being obtuse or annoyingly pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you cannot use `typeof` on a custom class. Using `instanceof` works.  The error literally means that you cannot use `typeof` for anything other than `'"string" | "number" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"'`.

Comment: `EnrollmentCase` would be (without other information) identified as `object` by `typeof` (try to log the call and see). On my side the switch block works with typeof and object. (not your desired behavior). Also regarding your comment above, I'd have you noticed that in a shop you'd have to pay, have you paid when registering to SO?

Comment: No, but I didn't do anything wrong.  Do you need me to find you a scenario in which I wouldn't have to pay?  Okay, how about--because we have single-payer health care here in Canada--"Doctor, I fell off my bike, my brain fell out, and now I have to have people tell me sentences with question marks at the end."  We could've exchanged pleasantries and been about our day, but he had to grab his pointy stick and jab me with it.

Comment: Yep Bluebaron is right. Here it is in the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html